# Show protected methods in SWAGGER (RESTLER 3)

Tags: php, restler

Im making an API, and I really like the SWAGGER interface for methods, but all my API requests will need to be protected and verified by Basic Auth. So any of those protected methods or classes will be available for SWAGGER. Is there any way to show them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing the following in your index.php will enable listing of protected methods

```
use \Luracast\Restler\Resources;

Resources::$hideProtected = false;
```

Accessing Basic Auth protected api from swagger will work just fine. But authenticating and getting through basic auth will require some work done on the swagger ui side

Comment: Soy I guess I will always get FALSE during the __isAllowed, when using SWAGGER. Sorry I cant make it code block style :(

<?php
use Luracast\Restler\iAuthenticate;
use Luracast\Restler\RestException;

class VerdeAuth implements iAuthenticate
{
    
    function __isAllowed()
    {
     //print_r ($_SERVER);
     if(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])){
      if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']=='GUEST' && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']=='GUEST' ){
       return TRUE;
      }
     }
     throw new RestException(401, 'Basic Authentication Required');
    }
    
}

Comment: See https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui#header-parameters you easily do basic authentication with Swagger UI 2 now!

Comment: Your are right.. Im using the #input_apiKey example, but I always get TypeError: window.authorizations is undefined in Console after unfocusing from the input field.

Answer (score 0):

I read this on the SWAGGER docs but.. I need to dynamically send user & password typed using SWAGGER UI input fields.. and then convert them for Basic Auth. So actually the question is how to add user&pwd fields into every SWAGGER request and set them to be sent via Basic Auth headers.

```
    // add a new ApiKeyAuthorization when the api-key changes in the ui.
$('#input_apiKey').change(function() {
  var key = $('#input_apiKey')[0].value;
  if(key && key.trim() != "") {
    window.authorizations.add("key", new ApiKeyAuthorization("api_key", key, "header"));
  }
})
```